# ¿Como crear una tabla con la columna izquierda fija y cabecera fija que funcione en todos los navegadores?

Tags: html, css3, tablas, scroll

lo que quiero hacer es que el lado izquierdo sea fijo, nose mucho de css asi que buscando informacion solo pude hacer la cabecera fija, pero nose como hacer el lado izquierdo de `productos` que sea fijo tambien para que se haga scroll tanto vertical como horizontalmente asi que en esta parte me quede truncado sin poder avanzar.

Esto es lo que hice hasta ahora

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  thead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  
  .table-responsive {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th class="header" scope="col" colspan="14">Dias Calendario</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="header" scope="col">Producto</th>
        <th class="header" scope="col">01</th>
        <th class="header" scope="col">02</th>
        <th class="header" scope="col">03</th>
        <th class="header" scope="col">04</th>
        <th class="header" scope="col">05</th>
        <th class="header" scope="col">06</th>
        <th class="header" scope="col">07</th>
        <th class="header" scope="col">08</th>
        <th class="header" scope="col">09</th>
        <th class="header" scope="col">10</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Manzana</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Platano</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fresa</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Leche</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Naranja</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Atun</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>X</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Si no me entendieron, quier que `productos` sea fijo para hacer scroll horizontalmente ya que los dias "01-02-03" son los dias de los meses que llegan hasta el 30 y serviria mucho hacer ese scroll para que el usuario no tenga que estar viendo por `celular` que producto tiene marcado

Si me podrian ayudar en esto, gracias

**EDIT01**: Me he dado cuenta que la cabecera fija solo funciona en mozilla y no en chrome, hay alguna forma en que funcione ahi tambien?

**EDIT02**: Lo que quiero hacer exactamente es esto https://github.com/twlikol/GridViewScroll como ven esta la cabecera fija y columna izquierda fija

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba de la siguiente manera, no se si es lo que quieres lograr:

```css
table {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.static {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
}

.first-col {
  padding-left: 74.5px!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="static">
      <th scope="col">FIJAR</th>
      <th  scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
      <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
      <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
      <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
  <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
  <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
  <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
  <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
  <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
  <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
  <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
</tr><tr>
  <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
  <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
  <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
  <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="static" scope="row">FIJAR</th>
  <td class="first-col">Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
</tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Se me fija los productos, pero la cabecera con los dias no se me fija

Comment: Pero estas pidiendo fijar la columna izquierda en el post. Corrigelo, y especifica que quieres que la las primeras filas y la primera columna son las que quieres fijas..

Comment: Es lo que pedias en el post

Comment: @Excorpion si pero lo de la cebecera fija ya lo tengo y me di cuenta que solo funciona en mozilla y no en chrome, pedi que tambien pudiera ser fijo la columna izquierdo agregando a lo que ya tengo (la cabecera fija), igual lo editare

Comment: Alli te edite la respuesta, verifica si es lo que deseas

Comment: No soy muy bueno explicando con palabras, pero quiero algo similar a esto https://github.com/twlikol/GridViewScroll (cabecera fija y columna izquierda fija), disculpa por no explicar correctamente

Comment: Verifica nuevamente la respuesta que te di, es lo que estas intentando realizar. Obviamente tienes que adaptarlo a tus datos.

Comment: @francofernandez cuando hago scroll horizontalmente, la columna izquierda se queda fija y es lo que quiero, pero cuando lo hago verticalmente, la cabecera de los dias no se queda fija

Comment: @bemoba1437 El problema es que has hecho que franco solo vea lo de la columna izquierda, si aplicas su solución, no funcionará lo que has solicitado, por que el corrigió esos errores. Ahora, el ha actualizado su respuesta conforme tu correcta solicitud. Por favor checkea y respóndele a el. (ya lo has hecho)

Comment: @bemoba1437 fijate ahora, modifique la posicion de .static a 'fixed' para que te permita dejar fija la primera fila y la primara columna.

Comment: @francofernandez Perfecto, gracias. Solo una cosa adicional, la tabla que tengo esta dentro de un div con un tamaño especifico, y con el codigo que pusiste sobrepasa ese tamaño, hay alguna forma de que respete el tamaño del div(height)?

Comment: De nada. Te sugiero probar borrar del archivo css el termino 'display: block;' y probar si te respeta los tamaños que tiene definida tu 'div'.